# Using FAAST as a substitute of a mouse

Tags: kinect

Im having problems with FAAST. I am currently using the program as a substitute of a mouse by choosing velocity. But the mouse movement is very jittery and it is hard for users to navigate around. Is there any way to make it smoother? Or better, is there any other better substitute?

Answer (score 0):

The official Kinect for Windows SDK has built in smoothing parameters:

```
kinectSensorManager.TransformSmoothParameters =
    new TransformSmoothParameters
    {
        // as the smoothing value is increased responsiveness to the raw data
        // decreases; therefore, increased smoothing leads to increased latency.
        Smoothing = 0.5f,
        // higher value corrects toward the raw data more quickly,
        // a lower value corrects more slowly and appears smoother.
        Correction = 0.5f,
        // number of frames to predict into the future.
        Prediction = 0.5f,
        // determines how aggressively to remove jitter from the raw data.
        JitterRadius = 0.05f,
        // maximum radius (in meters) that filtered positions can deviate from raw data.
        MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f
    };
```

I do not know if OpenNI has a direct call to smoothing functions.  The concepts could be manually coded using standard algorithms for such things.

You can also add in a movement buffer.  Check if the hand coordinates have moved by a specific delta before updating the location.  This helps remove jitter, but the cursor will jump more noticeably.  It is all a trade off, and helps show how a gesture input is not appropriate for controlling something that requires more precision.